# Change Content View of Android PopUpWindow

Tags: android

I'm just wondering if there's a way to change the content view of a PopUpWindow when it's already open.

According to the documentation for setContentView(View contentView):
*This method has no effect if called when the popup is showing.*

I tried hiding the content view with getContentView().setVisibility(View.GONE) and changing it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Try creating two layouts within your layout file, with one toggled off onCreate. OnClick hide the initial one, and show the alternate one.

Comment: Yeah, that was my backup plan, which does work, but I was hoping to be able to just swap views so I can keep things more modular.

Comment: That's where fragments are handy. Using FragmentTransactions to swap fragments OnClick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try extending `PopUpWindow` class to call `setContentView` in its constructor. Something like.-

```
public class CustomPopUpWindow extends PopUpWindow {
    public DialogParent(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    }
}
```